# Why does this Swift prepareForSegue function override have instantiation?

Tags: ios, oop, swift, overriding, segue

I'm learning Swift and I am working through passing items from one segue to another. From what it seems to me in the code, you are creating a new ViewController object called "secondVC". In line 3, it seems to me like it's duplicating the segue.destinationViewController by setting this new controller equal to the segue.destinationViewController. In other words, I don't understand how secondVC is actually a reference to this second view controller, instead of being a duplicated instance. Where is my fault in thinking? Here is the code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 var secondVC:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
 secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
 secondVC.delegate = self
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm learning swift too - From my own experience, you use prepareForSegue to pass in data to the secondVC right before the segue starts.

Here's some sample code. I use prepareForSegue to pass in task data into the second view controller. There are other ways to do this, this is just one way.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showTaskDetail" {
        let detailVC: TaskDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TaskDetailViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as TaskModel
        detailVC.detailTaskModel = thisTask
        detailVC.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! So then is detailVC a reference to segue.destinationViewController or a separate object that you're modifying?

Comment: detailVC is a reference to TaskDetailViewController which is the designation segue view controller. And np. If you have other questions please ask. Cheers